# Print PHP variables each in different fields in html

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm using php and ajax to validate a html form.

Currently, when I submit my form, js print my php variables in html as one string, but I want to print them in different places, for that I've prepared span tags below each form field. For example, I want print $nameErr in the  below name field, $numberErr in the  below number field... etc.

For this my logic says I need first to save all my error variables in one array and then call it with ajax, but I don't know how to do this.

I would like to use pure js.

**JS**

```js
submitBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
  myForm.onsubmit = function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  var phpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  phpRequest.open('POST', 'form.php');
  phpRequest.onload = function(){        
    phpMessage.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', phpRequest.responseText);
  }
  phpRequest.send();
});
```

**PHP**

```php
$nameErr = $numberErr = '';
$fieldsErr = array($numberErr, $numberErr);

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
  if(empty($_POST['name'])){
    echo $nameErr = 'Name is required';
  }else{
    $name = test_input($_POST['name']);
  }
  if(empty($_POST['number'])){
    echo $numberErr = 'Number is required';
  }else{
    $number = test_input($_POST['number']);
  }      
}
```

**HTML**

```html
  <form method="post">
  <label>
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your name*">
    <span class="status-field-message"></span>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="text" name="number" placeholder="Your phone number*">
    <span class="status-field-message"></span>
  </label>      
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Output variables as json in php with `json_encode`.
For example in php:

```
$errors = [];

if(empty($_POST['some])) {
    $errors['some'] = 'empty';
}

echo json_encode($errors);
```

and handle this data in pure js:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://someurl.net/page.php?param=123";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var myArr = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        myFunction(myArr);
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();

function myFunction(arr) {
    var out = "";
    var i;
    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        out += arr[i].some;
    }
    document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but how would that code looks in pure js? I forgot mention I would like to use just js.

Answer (score 0):

```
submitBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
  myForm.onsubmit = function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  var phpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

  phpRequest.open('POST', 'form.php');
  phpRequest.onload = function(){        
      phpMessage.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', phpRequest.responseText);
  }
  phpRequest.send();

  response = JSON.parse(phpRequest.responseText);

  document.getElementById('/name error div id/').innerHTML = response.nameError
  document.getElementById('/number error div id/').innerHTML = response.numberError
});
```

This assumes the json response has an array defining nameError and numberError as key-value pairs.